# How can I pass a LinkedList of a sub class to function expecting LinkedList of the normal class?

Tags: java, linked-list, subclass

I got a function that expects a LinkedList of objects, is it possible to pass and use a LinkedList of a sub-class of those objects?

```java
public abstract class Car {...} //just for example

public class Audi extends Car {...}

public void showCars (LinkedList<Car> cars) {    //example function
    for (Car i : cars) {            
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}

public void test () {
    LinkedList<Audi> audis = new LinkedList<Audi>();

    audis.add(new Audi(...));    //just for example so that the list is not empty
    showCars(audis);              //this says that its expecting a LinkedList<Cars>
                                 //but got LinkedList<Audi>
}
```

It says that showCars expects LinkedList<Cars> but got LinkedList<Audi>. This is just a very simple code outline which hopefully shows my problem.

Comment: The error is because `LinkedList<Audi>` is not a subclass of `LinkedList<Car>` even though `Audi extends Car`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways of doing this:

**Change the accepting method signature**

The method you call should accept a list of Cars or its subclasses for this to work, and you have to define it that way. Change your showCars method signature to the following:

```
public void showCars (LinkedList<? extends Car> cars)
```

You can read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html for more information.

**Change the type of the list you pass as parameter**

Based on the rightful comment from @JohnBollinger, there is another way. You can declare your list as a list of cars, and send it to your method, instead of a list of Audis:

```
public abstract class Car {...} //just for example

public class Audi extends Car {...}

public void showCars (LinkedList<Car> cars) {    //example function
    for (Car i : cars) {            
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}

public void test () {
    LinkedList<Car> audis = new LinkedList<>();

    audis.add(new Audi(...));    //just for example so that the list is not empty
    showCars(audis);              //this says that its expecting a LinkedList<Cars>
                                 //but got LinkedList<Audi>
}
```

Remember than a list with a `Class` generic type will accept also objects of its subclasses.This would preserve the original method signature and leave the responsibility on the caller to provide the properly typed `LinkedList`. This would also be the proper way to do this when the method you are calling is provided by a library or other source you have no access to.

Comment: It's probably also worth mentioning that `LinkedList<Audi>` is not a subclass of `LinkedList<Car>` even though `Audi extends Car` which is why we need wildcards.

Comment: ... but if the method requires a list with the specific parameter type `Car`, then that is what you must present.  Consider that if the method expects a `LinkedList<Car>` then it may assume that it can add a `Volvo` to that list, but it would be incorrect for it to do so if the argument were really a `LinkedList<Audi>`.

Answer (score -2):

You can try something like that:

```
public void test () {
    LinkedList<? extends Car> audis = new LinkedList<Audi>();
    LinkedList pleaseDontDoIt = audis;
    pleaseDontDoIt.add(new Audi());
    showCars(pleaseDontDoIt);
}
```

but this is totally unsafe

Comment: Java will warn you of an unchecked cast doing this. It is a bad practice, which -may- be required when interacting with pre-1.5 java libraries, but generally warnings should not be ignored.

Comment: Yep it is unsafe cast. I mentioned it under the code.